# Enable class methods without SFINAE

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, c++14

I'm looking for a way to enable class methods **without SFINAE**, maybe through inheritance.

[Im working on an improved version of std::function](https://github.com/Naios/Playground/blob/master/function.hpp) (functor class with `operator()`) which qualifier (const, volatile) is dependent on it's template argument for example:

- `myfunctor<void()>` provides `operator() ()`
- `myfunctor<void() const>` provides `operator() () const`
- `myfunctor<void() volatile>` provides `operator() () volatile`

and so on.

The main reason why i can't use SFINAE to solve this is that if i use SFINAE the operator() needs to be templated like:

```
template<typename R = ReturnType>
auto operator() (Args&&... args)
    -> std::enable_if_t<!Constant && !Volatile, R>
{
    return (*_impl)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template<typename R = ReturnType>
auto operator() (Args&&... args) const volatile
    -> std::enable_if_t<Constant && Volatile, R>
{
    return (*_impl)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

which means the `operator()` isn't referenceable anymore through using:

```
&my_functor<void() const>::operator()
```

My first intention was to use superclasses where i can inherit the `operator()` methods from but the methods still need to have access to the main implementation which is contained by a `std::unique_ptr` which holds a virtual class, and i don't want to pass a reference of the `std::unique_ptr` to the superclass.

**Is there another or better way to enable class methods without templating it (which excludes SFINAE).**

Comment: Note that hardcoding `Args&&` won't let you pass lvalues that could be normally copied (`Args&&` forces rvalues if reference collapsing doesn't take place)

Comment: Interesting thanks, what do you suggest to improve the signature then?

Comment: I suggest that you use `Args... args` instead (forwarding can stay as is)

Comment: In the pimpl, use `Args&&...` instead of `Args...`, as it will only be called from your `()`, which will forward into it (moving values).  In the public interface, use `Args...`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *operator() isn't referenceable anymore (...)*

With the SFINAE-based approach the operator is still accessible, with syntax:

```
&my::functor<void() const>::operator()<>
//                                    ↑↑
```

> *My first intention was to use superclasses where i can inherit the operator() methods from but the methods still need to have access to the main implementation which is contained by a std::unique_ptr*

You can use the CRTP idiom, so that `impl` is accessible by down-casting `this`:

```
template <typename /*Fn*/, bool /*NonCopyable*/, bool /*Constant*/, bool /*Volatile*/>
class function;

template <typename CRTP>
struct call_operator;

template <typename ReturnType, typename... Args, bool NonCopyable>
struct call_operator<function<ReturnType(Args...), NonCopyable, true, false>>
{
    using func = function<ReturnType(Args...), NonCopyable, true, false>;

    ReturnType operator()(Args&&... args) const
    {
        return (*static_cast<const func*>(this)->_impl)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

template <typename ReturnType, typename... Args, bool NonCopyable>
struct call_operator<function<ReturnType(Args...), NonCopyable, true, true>>
{
    using func = function<ReturnType(Args...), NonCopyable, true, true>;

    ReturnType operator()(Args&&... args) const volatile
    {
        return (*static_cast<const volatile func*>(this)->_impl)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

template<typename ReturnType, typename... Args, bool NonCopyable, bool Constant, bool Volatile>
class function<ReturnType(Args...), NonCopyable, Constant, Volatile> : call_operator<function<ReturnType(Args...), NonCopyable, Constant, Volatile>>
{
    friend struct call_operator<function<ReturnType(Args...), NonCopyable, Constant, Volatile>>;

    std::unique_ptr<wrapper_impl<ReturnType(Args...)>> _impl;

public:
    function()
        : _impl(new fake_wrapper_impl<ReturnType(Args...)>()) { }

    using call_operator<function<ReturnType(Args...), NonCopyable, Constant, Volatile>>::operator();    
};
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/58a641dfa6b11073)

Comment: Thank you for your amazing approach